# Cómo simular un click con jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5

Estoy realizando una página web que al realizar comandos de voz (con artyom.js), realiza la acción que se desee. Pero hay cosas que no puedo hacer como si lo hiciera con mouse, así que me gustaría saber cómo hacer click a un id, con jQuery. Así, cuando se le de un comando a artyom, se haga el click, como si se hiciera con el mouse.

Estuve mirando, y el código que vi esa algo simple: `$("#iniciar_sesion").click();`, pero esto no funciona. E incluso usé este: `$("#iniciar_sesion").get(0).click();`, pero tampoco. Agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: $("#iniciar_sesion").click(); funcionará dentro de una función que este escuchando un evento previo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes que simular el clic por medio del evento [trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) de **jQuery**, así:

```js
$("#btn_accion").on('click', function(){
  console.log('Acción ejecutada!')
})

$('#btn_accion').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn_accion">Acción</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esas funciones son para escuchar el click, el click se puede emitir con `.trigger( "click" );` , tambien puedes emitir un submit a un form.

Comment: Gracias, gracias ,il...despues de horas leo este post...muchas gracias !!!